# Modify checkbox change() event to wait for other actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a pretty big list of checkboxes that all perform an action when you check/uncheck one:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    DoSomething();
});
```

The `DoSomething()` method is actually pretty heavy. I've run into a problem where if someone starts clicking multiple checkboxes in a short period of time, it causes the method to be called every single time,

I'd like to limit that so that if the user clicks several of those checkboxes within the span of a second or two, that it will only call `DoSomething()` once.

Is there a way to wait for a couple seconds until the user is done checking checkboxes before I call `DoSomething()`?

Comment: Check out the [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)/[debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) methods in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). If you're fine with using that as a library, that's exactly what you need. Otherwise you could just look at the source code and copy the methods you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Moving my comment to an answer.</sub>

Check out the [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)/[`_.debounce`](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) methods in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). If you're fine with using that as a library, that's exactly what you need. Otherwise you could just look at the source code and copy the methods you need.

The following example will wait one second since the last checkbox was checked before executing the function:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0Leq82qg/)

```js
var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(function() {
  console.log('Debounced');
}, 1000);

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(debouncedFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

As stated above, if you don't want to include underscore in your project, then you could simply scrape the `_.debounce` method. Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cc35bzne/).

```js
var debouncedFunction = debounce(function() {
  console.log('Debounced');
}, 1000);

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(debouncedFunction);

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;

  var later = function() {
    var last = new Date().getTime() - timestamp;

    if (last < wait && last >= 0) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
    } else {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) {
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
      }
    }
  };

  return function() {
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    if (!timeout) timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) {
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      context = args = null;
    }

    return result;
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the input while `DoSomething()` is running:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    DoSomething();
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
var Timer;
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    clearTimeout(Timer);
    Timer = setTimeout(function(){
        MyFunction();
    }, 1000);
});

function MyFunction(){
    console.log("Timeout");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you can create your own debounce function like this:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;

    console.log('onfunct');
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

And then call it like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(
    debounce(function(ev) {
        alert('Do something here');
    }, 1000, 0)
);
```

To effectively wait for 1 second after a checkbox is checked. If `immediate` flag is set to 1 (or true) then the event will happen on the leading edge rather than at the end.

[Test the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/24tpzqwo/)